# Matter: Couldn't found device/Cann't connected to the network

Tags: android

As per the Matter documentation, I just tried to connect Matter sample app to one of matter physical device(Tapo Light L535E) but didn't get connecting successful so that my question is -
Is there any Hub required for connectivity using Matter sample app?

Reference:
https://developers.home.google.com/samples/matter-app

Making request for commissioning device

```
val commissionDeviceRequest =
            CommissioningRequest.builder()
                .setCommissioningService(ComponentName(context, AppCommissioningService::class.java))
                .build()
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you confirmed the minimum requirement for integration of matter SDK.Here you can troubleshot on [matter official documentation] https://developers.home.google.com/matter/troubleshooting